# Как правильно решить проблему с Actor?

Tags: java, libgdx

В данной момент при моем коде квадрат и треугольник передвигаются одновременно, а мне нужно, чтобы они передвигались только после их выбора. Пожалуйста помогите.

```
public class Figure extends Actor {
    private TextureRegion textureRegion;
    private Rectangle rectangle;

    public Figure(){
        super();
        textureRegion= new TextureRegion();
        rectangle= new Rectangle();

    }
    public void setTextureRegion(Texture t){
        textureRegion.setRegion(t);
        setSize(t.getWidth(),t.getHeight());
        rectangle.setSize(t.getWidth(),t.getHeight());
    }

    public Actor hit(float x, float y, boolean touchable) {
        if (touchable && getTouchable() != Touchable.enabled) return null;
        return x >= 0 && x < 800 && y >= 0 && y < 600 ? this : null;
    }
    public void act(float dt){
        super.act(dt);

    }


    public void draw(Batch batch,float parentAlpha){
        super.draw(batch,parentAlpha);
        Color c=getColor();
        batch.setColor(c.r,c.g,c.b,c.a);
        if(isVisible())
            batch.draw(textureRegion,getX(),getY(),getOriginX(),getOriginY(),getWidth(),getHeight(),getScaleX(),getScaleY(),getRotation());
    }

}

public class TriAngle extends Figure {

    private Vector2 position;
    private float w = 800;
    private float h = 600;


    public TriAngle() {

    }

    @Override
    public Actor hit(float x, float y, boolean touchable) {
        return super.hit(x, y, touchable);
    }

    public void act(float dt) {
        super.act(dt);

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
            this.moveBy(-w/4,0);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
            this.moveBy(w/4,0);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
            this.moveBy(0,h/4);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN ))
            this.moveBy(0,-h/4);


    }
}

public class Quad extends Figure{
    private float w=800;
    private float h=600;
    public Quad(){

        super();
    }
    public void act(float dt) {

        super.act(dt);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
            this.moveBy(-w/4,0);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
            this.moveBy(w/4,0);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
            this.moveBy(0,h/4);
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN ))
            this.moveBy(0,-h/4);


        }
    }

    public class MyGdxGame extends GameOsnova {

    private TriAngle triAngle;
    private Quad quad;
    private Figure background;

    private float w=800;
    private float h=600;
    @Override
    public void initialize() {


    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {

    }

    @Override
    public void create () {

        mainStage =new Stage();

        background=new Figure();
        background.setTextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Pole.png")));
        background.setPosition(0,0);
        background.setSize(w,h);
        mainStage.addActor(background);


        triAngle= new TriAngle();
        triAngle.setTextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("TriAngle.png")));
        triAngle.setPosition(0,0);
        triAngle.setSize(w/4,h/4);
        //triAngle.setBounds(0,0,w/4,h/4);
        mainStage.addActor(triAngle);


        quad= new Quad();
        quad.setTextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("start_button.png")));
        quad.setPosition(3*w/4,0);
        quad.setSize(w/4,h/4);
       // quad.addAction(show);
        mainStage.addActor(quad);


    }


    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        mainStage.dispose();

    }
}

public abstract class GameOsnova extends Game {

    protected Stage mainStage;

        public abstract void initialize();

           public void render(){

        float dt= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

          mainStage.act(dt);
         // mainStage.hit(200,400,false);
        // mainStage.hit(0,0,true);
         update(dt);
         Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
         mainStage.draw();
    }

    public abstract void update(float dt);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ответ нашёл в книге Java Game Development with LibGDX From Beginner to Professional Second Edition в 9 главе (Drag-and-Drop Games). В этой главе рекомендуют создать замечательный класс `DragAndDropActor`.

```
public class DragAndDropActor extends BaseActor {
    private DragAndDropActor self;
    private float grabOffsetX;
    private float grabOffsetY;

    public DragAndDropActor(float x, float y, Stage s) {
        super(x, y, s);
        self = this;
        addListener(
            new InputListener() {
                public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float offsetX, float offsetY, int pointer, int button) {
                    self.grabOffsetX = offsetX;
                    self.grabOffsetY = offsetY;
                    self.toFront();
                    return true;
                }

                public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float offsetX, float offsetY, int pointer) {
                    float deltaX = offsetX - self.grabOffsetX;
                    float deltaY = offsetY - self.grabOffsetY;
                    self.moveBy(deltaX, deltaY);
                }

                public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float offsetX, float offsetY, int pointer, int button) {
                    // will add code later
                }
            });
    }

    public void act(float dt) {
        super.act(dt);
    }
}
```

Comment: отсылки к внешним ресурсам — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе с отсылкой и описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // проще говоря: то, что вы написали в поле для ответа, никак не отвечает на сам вопрос.